# Error when selecting the textfield by tag in a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with TextFields, I created a command in which you add one more line in my table and thus creates another text field within the table, I'm differentiating each text field by entering a particular tag as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView2 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{//Ja explicado anteriormente

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ComissoesTableViewCell";//Ja explicado anteriormente

    ComissoesTableViewCell *cell = (ComissoesTableViewCell *)[tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];//Ja explicado anteriormente

    if (cell == nil){//Ja explicado anteriormente

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ComissoesTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];//Ja explicado anteriormente

        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];//Ja explicado anteriormente
    }

    cell.data.tag = indexPath.row;

Return Cell;

}
```

Below is the command in which inserts a new row in the table, this method is only called when the User clicks a button within the existing view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    iArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    numeroCampos = 1;
    [tableView reloadData];

}

-(void)AdicionarField{

    iArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    numeroCampos++;

    for(int x=0;x<numeroCampos;x++){

        [iArray addObject:[self getByTag:x]];

    }
```

}

Have you noticed that it adds a new object to the array and the object it adds nothing is a kind of backup text fields, this method called 'getByTag' Gets the text contained within the existing text fields within the table through the tag:

```
-(NSString *)getByTag:(NSInteger)myTag {

    NSLog(@"Get By Tag -> %d",myTag);

    NSString *texto = @"null";

    NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [tableView numberOfSections]; ++j)
    {
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i)
        {
            [cells addObject:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]]];
        }
    }

    for (ComissoesTableViewCell *cell in cells)
    {
        if (cell.data.tag == myTag){
            texto = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cell.data.text];

        }
    }

    return texto;
}
```

The problem is that this command works almost perfectly, begins from the moment I enter the tenth row of the column the app crashes and the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

I'm a few days trying to solve this problem but I can not find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Exception stack trace tells you the problem, you are trying to insert nil object to array which causes uncaught exception, check for nil before inserting any object to the array.

Comment: @Idindu! I see the problem and the problem is in my table!, My tableView have 990x550 pixels, and when we insert more than 9 rows automatic the tableView create a scroll, and the textField tag = 1 not visible to the user! and this is causing problem because the textfield tag = 1 now is disable, but for why? how can I solve this?

Comment: You seem to be using UITableViewCells (ComissoesTableViewCell) to store your data.  The getByTag method looks extremely inefficient (it has doubly-nested for-loops and the method itself is called in a for-loop).  The datasource of a UITableView (or any view) should be kept independently in model objects and structured in a way that allows quick access (NSDictionary, NSArray, etc).

Comment: Well @Anna, for now The only solution I can see for this is, when the number of rows in tableView go to 9, I increased the height of my tableView once my tableView is inserted inside a scrollView, so I increased the height of the table and scroll in relation to the number of lines